# Repeating Information In Word, Like A 2" x 2" Header

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I have a document template setup that is basically a giant table with a left column and a right column. The entire page has a header with a logo and a pattern that spans the whole width of the page.

What I need to do is create a "header" in the left column, so that the same data appears on every page. Think of it like a two col resume, and you want your Name/Title/Contact info to appear on every page at the top of the left column, but the right column should start at the same height, not below it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Bonus info:
The page is actually a series of content controls that are populated in C# via a customXMLParts file. Not sure if that makes a difference to you. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to do it conceptually, since to my knowledge, a header must span the whole width of the page.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a table:

- Create a two column table with several rows;
- Select the two cells in the top row;
- From the *Layout* tab in the ribbon, select *Merge Cells*
- From the *Layout* tab in the ribbon, select *Repeat Header Rows*
- Resize the header row as needed to make it line up over just one column if you don't want it to span the width of the table (you have to do this with just the header row selected).

You could also just put the repeating information in a document header instead of the table header. That would mean it would repeat on every page of the current section. Most documents have only one section, but you can insert section breaks and define different headers (and footers) for each section.

Comment: This seems to do everything I want, except that the header row (which I resized to only be on the left) pushes down the start of the content on the right side. Is there a way to have a header row on just the left and not the right? I see it auto-assumes the first row is the header.